# R Vectorize a Repeat Loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function where the standard is to use a `repeat` loop to calculate the answer and I'm having a problem writing a "Vectorized" function for this. The function works when I call it on a single line of code; however, when I put it in a `data frame` with `mutate` it gives an error because only the first value is used. I can get around this by using `rowwise` however that's probably not the best method.

How can I rewrite the `repeat` loop to work with `mutate`? Below is an example of the function.

```
mean_estimate <- function(x, y) {
  mean <- (x + y) / 2
  out <- x
  repeat{
    out <- out + 0.1
    if (out >= mean) {
      break
    }
  }
  return(out)
}

# Check function for simple numbers
mean_estimate(100, 200)

# Check function for vectors
mean_estimate(seq(100, 200, 20), seq(200, 300, 20))

# Check function for data frame
df <- data_frame(
  var1 = runif(10, min = 120, max = 150),
  var2 = runif(10, min = 220, max = 250)
)

wrong <- df %>%
  mutate(wrong = mean_estimate(var1, var2))

right <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(right = mean_estimate(var1, var2))

comb <- wrong %>%
  left_join(right, by = c("var1", "var2")) %>%
  mutate(error = wrong - right)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `map2` which would be faster than `rowwise`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(right = map2_dbl(var1, var2, mean_estimate))
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! It is appreciated. I guess what I'm looking for is a way to rewrite the function to avoid the repeat statement, but since this isn't actually the code, it must be a bad question and difficult to answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized function without a loop:

```
mean_estimate_vec <- function(x, y) {
  x + floor(((x + y) / 2 - x + 0.1) * 10) / 10
}

df <- data.frame(
  var1 = runif(10, min = 120, max = 150),
  var2 = runif(10, min = 220, max = 250)
)

all.equal(
  #your function:
  apply(df, 1, function(z) mean_estimate(z[1], z[2])), 
  #vectorized:
  with(df, mean_estimate_vec(var1, var2))
)
#[1] TRUE
```

Sorry, I have no desire to install the tidyverse. Therefore only base functions in this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I'm trying to see how I can apply it to the actual code!